# Why is the "ad hoc network" option missing when creating a network connection in Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, wireless-networking, networking, ad-hoc-network

When I attempt to create a network connection in Windows Vista, there is no "ad hoc network" option available. Why is this?

The options available are (translated):

- Connect to the Internet
- Configure a wireless router or access point
- Create a remote connection
- Connect to a workplace

Comment: You need a Wireless Card to do Ad hoc.

Comment: I assume that my network card is wireless since I can locate other computers, and the only network connection going through a wire to my computer is my internet connection. Regardless, is there any way to check whether or not a network card is wireless or not? In the device manager, the device is simply called "NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller."

Comment: After disconnecting my Internet wire I can no longer locate any other computers, so I guess my network card simply isn't wireless. Still, I thought there would be an easy way to find this out inside Windows. Is there?

Comment: Anyway the real question is, What are you trying to accomplish ? Why are you looking for an ad hoc connection, which is useless when already connected to the network.

Comment: My guess is that 'starter' versions of Vista and 7 just don't have that option to create and Ad-Hoc connections.

Comment: Your "network" and "internet wire" are one and the same.  The network is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your wireless network card is turned on.

Go in to the "Network and Sharing Center", and on the left click "Manage Wireless Networks", from here click the add button and "Ad-Hoc network" should be one of the options.

However, if your Wireless is on, you should be able to get to it from the screen you were on  -

[image]

If it isn't there, it is possible you have some sort of other error.

Comment: In my device manager under network cards, I have a single device named "NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller" that is not disabled. Additionally, I can find other computers when I activate "Network identification," so I would assume that the card is turned on.

Comment: Nvidia nForce Networking afaik is not wireless. Go to command prompt and type ipconfig and look at device name (or click start and type "network connections" take a look at how many interfaces you have and see if any of them say wireless.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is for Vista, but if anyone is having this issue on windows 10, here is the solution.

1. Go to Start and the new "Windows Settings" and select "Network & Internet".
2. On the left side of the window, click "Mobile hotspot".
3. Slide the switch to the on position.

-- OPTIONAL --

4. Under "Network name" and "Network password", click the "Edit" button.
5. Change the network name and password to what ever you want.

Comment: From your description, it appears this does not refer to ad-hoc networks.

Comment: @DanielB Is there a difference between an ad-hoc network and a hotspot?

Comment: Yes, very much so. Hotspots are access points. [They run in infrastructure mode while ad-hoc is, well, ad-hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_LAN#Types_of_wireless_LANs).

Comment: That wasn't helpful. An ad hoc network creates a WiFi signal so that other devices can connect to the internet. So does a hotspot. To me they seem like they are the same. Am I missing something.

Comment: I don’t know any better way to put it, sorry. They’re completely different operating modes. One is a mesh network, the other is a star network with the access point at its center. The OP in this question asked about ad-hoc networking.

Comment: You might be right, but the only thing I have ever used adhoc for was to act as a temporary WiFi hotspot. I haven't had to use it in like 10 years but my router died on me yesterday and when I went to create an adhoc from my desktop, the adhoc option was gone. I played around a little bit and figured out there was a hotspot option that fixed my problem and did exactly what I wanted the adhoc to do. Admittedly, I only know the one thing about adhoc networks. If it does other things also, then I guess this isn't a solution for that. I guess it is less of a solution and more of a bandaid.

Answer (score 1):

To help others, not all wireless adapters can host a connection.

From [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/windows-81-ad-hoc-not-showing/5d75d887-ff59-425e-a480-9f80ada63627) they suggest running:

```
netsh wlan show drivers
```

Look for "Hosted network supported".  If you see no, you're out of luck

Comment: Ad-hoc networking is supported on all 802.11 adapters. It’s not the same as hosting a network.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to this problem is:

```
net start wlansvc
```

..if the WLAN AutoConfig service has been stopped then Ad-Hoc Networking won't show up.