# Why is the "ad hoc network" option missing in "Set Up a Connection or Network"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10-preview

Why is the "ad hoc network" option missing in "Set Up a Connection or Network" in Network and Sharing Center?

**even though** I can set it up in cmd (command prompt) with `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ABCDEF key=12345678`  & run it successfully with `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` without any connectivity problems

Source for cmd instructions [here](http://www.techverse.net/turn-pc-laptop-wifi-hotspot-without-using-software/)

also visited an old superuser question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/38656/why-is-the-ad-hoc-network-option-missing-when-creating-a-network-connection-in) which is similar but different from mine since

- wifi is working & I can setup ad hoc network through command prompt
- but the option to do so is missing in "Set Up a Connection or Network" in Network and Sharing Center
- windows 10 Version 10.0.11099

Is there a way I can get this option back?
or was the option removed by Microsoft (& its not just me)?

[image]

Comment: I've noticed this has been a problem since Windows 8... I've just resorted thus far to use of a batch file.